# recognize the client in wcf

Tags: wcf

Architecture of project

my wcf expose 11 endpoints,one of the endpoint ment for authentication and autherization. which returns the accountid of the user.this accountid is sent by client in every method for recozination.

need

i dont want to send the account id to every method ,all i want a way that can give me the accoint id automatically if the client is loggedin

Limitation...

1> i cant use membership.

2>i can,t use persession mode of wcf becose it creates new session for every endpoint

3> cant use outgoinfheaders on client side ..

is there any custom way to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like scenario for federated security but it would conflict with some of your requirements.

1. You don't need membership.
2. You don't need per session services
3. You need somehow pass the token - if you cannot use custom outgoing SOAP header and configure it in some central place, you will have to pass the token inside the message body and you will have to configure it as a parameter for each service call.

Comment: yeah i konw header is the best way to do this,client do not want to send any information of loggedin user through header also

Comment: And where the client want to send the information? Both header and body are text content in the same message.

Comment: client dont want to send the information to wcf,once the user authenticated,client want that the wcf will reconize the account id automatically

Comment: That is not possible. In such case move all 11 endpoints into single one and use per session service with `IsInitiating` operation for login and `IsTerminating` operation for logout. It will still silently send some session Id unless you use net.tcp as transport.